# Spring boot project could not find or load main class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I am building a spring boot websocket application with a plugin loader built into it but when I package and run the jar it gives this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.github.omen.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.omen.Main
```

I've found by testing that both the plugin loader and the websocket app work as separate projects but will not load together. Below is my `pom.xml`, thank you in advance.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>io.github.omen</groupId>
    <artifactId>OmenChat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!--        plugin api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.OMEN44</groupId>
            <artifactId>OMENChat-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>4bf005d4ac</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        lombok-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--        logger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        spring boot-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>io.github.omen.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please configure mainClass in spring-boot-maven-plugin and remove maven-assembly-plugin.  Try as below:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
        <mainClass>io.github.omen.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution! The project now loads the plugins then runs the spring boot app!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is :

Got to Spring Initializer: https://start.spring.io/

Generate a new Maven / Java / SpringBoot project with version you prefer.

run it and check your system is fine

start adding your customizations one at a time in this project, and try after each modification.

In few minutes you'll have found the reason behind this error.

And if you are using spring-boot-maven-plugin then you don't need maven-assembly-plugin